# MacAlly keyboard model xkeyhub will not bring up the boot picker on iMac

Tags: keyboard, mac, startup

I have a MacAlly keyboard model xkeyhub that I use with a 2011 iMac. I want to be able to bring up the boot picker by simply holding down the Option key at startup. For some reason the boot picker does not show up. I have tried other keyboards with the same iMac and they do work. Ever a PC keyboard works by holding down the ALT key. Has anyone experienced this problem with this or another model MacAlly keyboard?

I have tried looking this keyboard up but all information and reviews for it has mysteriously disappeared. I would like to note that this keyboard also fails to show the boot picker on a 2010 MacBook Pro.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be something you need to take up with MacAlly tech support. It *sounds* like it is not sending the right keypress codes with the Option key held down. Failing another AD user with a similar/same keyboard MacAlly themselves may be your only recourse.